# Vertex Array Objects - Confusion regarding exactly what state information is saved about the currently bound vertex buffer

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-array-object

I'm working through the excellent tutorials at [arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html) while building a graphics engine and have discovered I don't understand VAOs as much as I thought I had.

From the tutorial [Chapter 5. Objects In Depth](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html)

> Buffer Binding and Attribute Association
>
> You may notice that glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER) is not on that list, even though it is part of the attribute setup for rendering. The binding to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER is not part of a VAO because the association between a buffer object and a vertex attribute does not happen when you call glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER). This association happens when you call glVertexAttribPointer.
>
> When you call glVertexAttribPointer, OpenGL takes whatever buffer is at the moment of this call bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and associates it with the given vertex attribute. Think of the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding as a global pointer that glVertexAttribPointer reads. So you are free to bind whatever you want or nothing at all to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER after making a glVertexAttribPointer call; it will affect nothing in the final rendering. So VAOs do store which buffer objects are associated with which attributes; but they do not store the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding itself.

I initially missed the last line "...but they do not store the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding itself". Before I noticed this line I thought that the currently bound buffer was saved once glVertexAttribPointer was called. Missing this knowledge, I built a mesh class and was able to get a scene with a number of meshes rendering properly.

A portion of that code is listed below. Note that I do not call glBindBuffer in the draw function.

```
// MESH RENDERING

/* ...            */
/* SETUP FUNCTION */
/* ...            */

// Setup vertex array object
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vertex_array_object_id);
glBindVertexArray(_vertex_array_object_id);

// Setup vertex buffers  
glGenBuffers(1, &_vertex_buffer_object_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertex_buffer_object_id);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertices.size() * sizeof(vertex), &_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Setup vertex attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(e_aid_position);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(e_aid_normal);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(e_aid_color);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(e_aid_tex);

glVertexAttribPointer(e_aid_position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(vertex, pos));
glVertexAttribPointer(e_aid_normal,   3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(vertex, norm));
glVertexAttribPointer(e_aid_color,    4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(vertex, col));
glVertexAttribPointer(e_aid_tex,      2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(vertex, tex));  

/* ...           */
/* DRAW FUNCTION */
/* ...           */

glBindVertexArray(_vertex_array_object_id);  
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _vertices.size());
```

Now that I'm about to start lighting I wanted to get some debug drawing up so I could verify all my normals are correct. Currently I just store all lines to be rendered for a frame in a vector. Since this data will likely change every frame, I'm using GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW and specify the data right before I render it.

Initially when I did this I would get garbage lines that would just point off into infinity. The offending code is below:

```
// DEBUG DRAW LINE RENDERING 

/* ...            */
/* SETUP FUNCTION */
/* ...            */

// Setup vertex array object
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vertex_array_object_id);
glBindVertexArray(_vertex_array_object_id);

// Setup vertex buffers  
glGenBuffers(1, &_vertex_buffer_object_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertex_buffer_object_id);
  // Note: no buffer data supplied here!!!

// Setup vertex attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(e_aid_position);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(e_aid_color);

glVertexAttribPointer(e_aid_position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(line_vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(line_vertex, pos));
glVertexAttribPointer(e_aid_color,    4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(line_vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(line_vertex, col));

/* ...           */
/* DRAW FUNCTION */
/* ...           */

glBindVertexArray(_vertex_array_object_id);
  // Specifying buffer data here instead!!!
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _line_vertices.size() * sizeof(line_vertex), &_line_vertices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, _line_vertices.size());
```

After a bit of hunting, as well as finding the detail I missed above, I found that if I call glBindBuffer before glBufferData in the draw function, everything works out fine.

I'm confused as to why my mesh rendering worked in the first place given this. Do I only need to call glBindBuffer again if I change the data in the buffer? Or is behavior undefined if you don't bind the buffer and I was just unlucky and had it work?

**Note that I am targeting OpenGL version 3.0.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do I only need to call glBindBuffer again if I change the data in the
>   buffer?

Yes, The VAO object remembers which buffers were bound each time you called `glVertexAttribPointer` whilst that VAO was bound, so you don't usually need to call `glBindBuffer` again. If you want to change the data in the buffer however, OpenGL needs to know which buffer you are changing, so you need to call `glBindBuffer` before calling `glBufferData`. It is irrelevant which VAO object is bound at this point.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. I have one minor detail that I'm still a little fuzzy on. Let's say I call glBindVertexArray with VAO 1 which remembers VBO 1 was bound when glVertexAttribPointer was called.Then I call glBindBuffer with VBO 2, followed by glDrawArrays. Which buffer should be used, VBO 1 or VBO 2? I don't believe this is something that one would normally do, I just want to make sure I understand what's going on.

Comment: VBO 1 will be used. Note that this is true whether or not you are using VAOs. Also you might have bound several VBOs whilst you had the VAO bound (perhaps a different one for each attribute). Once you have called glVertexAttribPointer the buffer bound at that time is the one which will be used.

Comment: OpenGL still confuses me a bunch. When exactly does the `VBO` "attach" to the `VAO` while the `VAO` is bound? Upon calling `glGenBuffers` or `glBindBuffers`? (Again, while the `VAO` is currently bound, of course).

Answer (score 1):

A Vertex Array object holds the data set by `glEnableVertexAttribArray`, `glDisableVertexAttribArray`, `glVertexAttribPointer`, `glVertexAttribIPointer`, `glVertexAttribDivisor` and `gl.bindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)`

To put it another way you could define a VAO as

```
struct VertexAttrib {
  GLint size;           // set by gVertexAttrib(I)Pointer
  GLenum type;          // set by gVertexAttrib(I)Pointer
  GLboolean normalize;  // set by gVertexAttrib(I)Pointer
  GLsizei stride;       // set by gVertexAttrib(I)Pointer
  GLint buffer;         // set by gVertexAttrib(I)Pointer (indirectly)
  void* pointer;        // set by gVertexAttrib(I)Pointer
  GLint divisor;        // set by gVertexAttribDivisor
  GLboolean enabled;    // set by gEnable/DisableVertexAttribArray
};

struct VertexArrayObject {
  std::vector<VertexAttrib> attribs;
  GLuint element_array_buffer;  // set by glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ..)
};
```

How many attributes there are can be queried with

```
GLint num_attribs;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &num_attribs)
```

You can think of GL's global state has having a pointer to a VertexArrayObject that is set with `glBindVertexArray`

```
struct GLGlobalState {
  VertexArrayObject default_vao;
  VertexArrayObject* current_vao = &default_vao;
  ...

  GLint current_array_buffer;  // set by glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)
}
GLGloalState gl_global_state;

void glBindVertexArray(GLint vao) {
  gl_global_state.current_vao = vao == 0 ? &default_vao : getVAOById(vao);
}
```

And you can think of the other functions listed above working like this

```
void glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint index) { 
  gl_global_state.current_vao->attribs[index].enabled = GL_TRUE;
}

void glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint index) { 
  gl_global_state.current_vao->attribs[index].enabled = GL_FALSE;
}

void glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized,
                      GLsizei stride, const void* pointer) { 
  VertexAttrib* attrib = &gl_global_state.current_vao->attribs[index];
  attrib->size = size;
  attrib->type = type;
  attrib->normalized = normalized;
  attrib->stride = stride;
  attrib->pointer = pointer;
  attrib->buffer = glGlobalState.current_array_buffer;
}

void glVertexAttribDivisor(GLuint index, GLuint divisor) {
  gl_global_state.current_vao->attribs[index].divisor = divisor;
}
```

It might be easier to see it visually

[image]

from [this diagram](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) though the diagram above shows `offset` instead of `pointer` since it's from WebGL which doesn't allow client side arrays, only vertex buffers, therefore the pointer field is always interpreted as an offset.

In OpenGL `pointer` is a pointer to user memory if the `buffer` field for that attribute is 0 (set indirectly, see above). It's an offset into a buffer if the `buffer` for an attribute is non-zero.

One thing **NOT** stored in an VAO are the attribute's constant values when it's disabled. If an attribute is disabled (they default to disabled, or you call `gl.disableVertexAttribArray`) then that attribute will get a constant value. The constant value can be set with [`glVertexAttrib???`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttrib.xhtml). These values are global. They are not part of VAO state.